# JSON message object is missing the id property

Tags: json, qt, websocket, qt5.5

When I tried to send an instance of a QObject based subclass to html client with QWebChannel, I get following error:

> JSON message object is missing the id property: {
>   "type": 3
>   }

The server-client connection itself is successful, only the object can not be sent. Probably anyone knows an answer?

To reproduce using the [Qt WebChannel Standalone Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-standalone-example.html) and load [file:///C:/Qt/5.5/Examples/Qt-5.5/webchannel/build-standalone-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/index.html?webChannelBaseUrl=ws://localhost:12345](http://file:///C:/Qt/5.5/Examples/Qt-5.5/webchannel/build-standalone-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/index.html?webChannelBaseUrl=ws://localhost:12345) in your web browser after running the Qt server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution.. I had to update my qwebchannel.js (look [here](https://github.com/qtproject/qtwebchannel/tree/dev/src/webchannel)), then it works...